# Sum values in column if the difference of two other columns is smaller than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  |      A      |      B     |        C        |          D           |     E       |
--|-------------|------------|-----------------|----------------------|-------------|-
1 |  Product    | sales_plan |  sales_actuals  |  purchase_quantity   |             |
2 |  Product_A  |     500    |       400       |         1200         |             |
3 |  Product_B  |     800    |       900       |         3000         |    10000    |
4 |  Product_C  |     300    |       490       |         2000         |             |
5 |  Product_D  |     900    |       820       |         7000         |             |
6 |  Product_E  |     200    |       250       |         5000         |             |
7 |  Product_F  |     700    |       600       |         4000         |             |
```

---

In `Cell E3` I want to sum up the `purchase_quantity` in `Column D` if the `sales_actuals > sales_plan`.

I know I could do this by inserting a helper column and then build the sum over this helper column. 
However, I would prefer a solution without this helper column.
Something like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C;C:C-B:B;"<0"))
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C7>B2:B7)*D2:D7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments the answer from JvdV is working:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C7>B2:B7)*D2:D7)
```