# Sum values in column if the difference of two other columns is smaller than 0 and an additional critieria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  |      A      |      B     |        C        |          D           |     E       |
--|-------------|------------|-----------------|----------------------|-------------|-
1 |  Product    | sales_plan |  sales_actuals  |  purchase_quantity   |             |
2 |  Product_A  |     500    |       400       |         1200         |   Product_B |
3 |  Product_B  |     800    |       900       |         3000         |     5000    |
4 |  Product_B  |     300    |       490       |         2000         |             |
5 |  Product_D  |     900    |       820       |         7000         |             |
6 |  Product_D  |     200    |       250       |         5000         |             |
7 |  Product_D  |     700    |       600       |         4000         |             |
```

---

Wit reference to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71867803/sum-values-in-column-if-the-difference-of-two-other-columns-is-smaller-than-0) in `Cell E3` I want to sum up the
`purchase_quantity` in `Column D`

a) if the `sales_actuals > sales_plan` and  
b) if the product matches with the entry in `Cell E2`.

I tried to go with this formula but could not make it work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C7>B2:B7)*D2:D7;A2:A7=E2)
```

How do I need to modify it to get the correct value?

Comment: You were close: `=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C7>B2:B7)*(A2:A7=E2)*D2:D7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments the answer from JvdV is working:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C7>B2:B7)*(A2:A7=E2)*D2:D7)
```